# Switching ribbon tabs in excel programmatically

Tags: c#, excel, .net-6.0, office-interop, office-automation

I am new to desktop automation and I want to automate some actions for Microsoft Excel. I have a nunit testing project which in which I am writing a test which basically navigates to "View" tab in ribbon bar and changes page layout.

I have written the following code

```
// Create an instance of Excel
Application excel = new Application();

// Make Excel visible
excel.Visible = true;
// Check if there are any open workbooks
if (excel.Workbooks.Count == 0)
{
    // Create a new workbook if there are none open
    excel.Workbooks.Add();
}

// Get the command bars object
CommandBars commandBars = excel.CommandBars;

// Activate the View tab in the ribbon
commandBars["Worksheet Menu Bar"].Controls["View"].ActivateTab();
```

but it's giving me error on CommandBars that type or namespace could not be found. I have added reference to Excel Object in COM.

I am using .net6 , Windows 11(on a VM) and office 2021.

Comment: There's been a rash of questions lately that all have the same underlying problem.  I *think* it has something to do with a Nuget package that has a bad mistake, it only provides the interop for Excel but not the other one you always have a dependency on.  Office.dll, it defines types that all programs that target an Office product need.  Like CommandBars.  Do avoid crummy Nuget packages, very strongly favor adding the Excel reference from the COM tab.  Also ensures you don't have versioning problems.

Comment: @HansPassant, How can I make verify versioning problem?

Answer (score 0):

Command Bars were deprecated and shouldn't be used any longer (except for running ribbon controls programmatically and etc.). Instead, you need to use the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) for customizing or dealing with the ribbon controls in Office applications. You need to use the [IRibbonUI.ActivateTabMso](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.iribbonui.activatetabmso) method which activates the specified built-in tab.

If you need to manage the UI in your tests you may consider using the [Accessibility API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/microsoft-active-accessibility) or any other libraries built on top of that API.

Comment: Sorry I am new with all this. Can you please provide me with a sample code for using IRibbonUi as I am not able to find it’s instance in excel.RibbonUi

Comment: An instance of the `IRibbonUI` interface is passed to the `onLoad` callback, see the [IRibbonUI object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.iribbonui) for more information.